# BeautifulSoup: stripping HTML tags from findAll ResultSet

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to strip all HTML tags from the ResultSet of `soup.html.body.findAll('td', {'class':'yfnc_h'})`

Currently, the ResultSet sometimes contains nested `<a href>`, `<td>`, and other tags. The only semi-solution I've found which acts upon the ResultSet (not the soup object) is `RSelement.string`

However, `.string` cannot handle inputs with multiple nested tags, e.g.

Input: `<td class="yfnc_h" align="right">53.50</td>`

Output: 53.50

Input: `<td class="yfnc_h" align="right"><b>51.97</b></td>`

Output: `None`

Input: `<td class="yfnc_h" align="right"><span id="yfs_c10_djx131116c00100000"> <b style="color:#000000;">0.00</b></span></td>`

Output: None

How do I strip all tags from the ResultSet output?

Comment: Is the output you show your desired output?

Comment: No, the output above is the actual, erroneous output. I would like to show 53.50 ; 51.97 ; 0.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `.text` attribute instead:

```
print RSelement.text
```

Comment: print RSelement.text gives me all "None" results.

Comment: @JackHuang Works fine for me when I do `BeautifulSoup('<td class="yfnc_h" align="right"><b>51.97</b></td>').text`. What version of BeautifulSoup are you using

Comment: Ok, that's strange. I'm getting "None" for `print` that exact code.

Comment: Got it. With bs4, the sample you tested works perfectly, though there's now a HTMLParseError for my original script. I'm currently using Python's built-in HTML parser, so maybe I'll give lxml a shot?

Comment: @JackHuang Hm, I don't have `lxml` installed on this machine (I think I have python's built-in), so I'm not entirely sure there. You could have a shot at lxml